# ds.reduce calls other funcs when using it to calculating cardinality

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a dataset that I ran through a filter and then a map. If I want to get the size of the dataset, I have two options:

1- To use cardinality: gives me "-2", so I'll have to use reduce

2- Using reduce: `train_ds.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy()`. Here's the code:

```py
def create_dataset(audio_paths, audio_classes):
    
    # create zip dataset
    ds = tf.data.Dataset.zip(
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(audio_paths),
        tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(audio_classes)
    )

    ds = ds.filter(lambda x, y: tf.py_function(exclude_short_tracks, [x], tf.bool))
    print(ds)
    
    # map each path to a spectrogram
    # contains the mel from all sources' first [SAMPLING_LENGTH] seconds.
    ds = ds.map(lambda x, y: (tf.py_function(make_mel, [x], tf.float32), y))
    print(ds)
    
    return ds

# return true only if the file is longer than SAMPLING_LENGTH
def exclude_short_tracks(path, label):
    # path = next(iter(path))
    path = path.numpy()[0].decode('ascii')
    print("path:", path)
    length = librosa.get_duration(path = path)
    print("length:",length)
    return length < SAMPLING_LENGTH

# get path, read audio data, pass it into next func to get mel, then return it
# this will be used in map (look above)
def make_mel(path):
    # the first x seconds of the track are imported
    audio_data, _ = librosa.load(
        path, sr = SAMPLING_RATE, duration = SAMPLING_LENGTH
    )
    mel = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(
        y = audio_data, sr = SAMPLING_RATE, n_mels = MEL_DETAIL, fmax = FREQ_CAP
    )
    
    return mel

train_ds = create_dataset(training_paths, training_genres)
valid_ds = create_dataset(validation_paths, validation_genres)

# try using reduce: doesn't work
print("Training dataset cardinality:", train_ds.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy())
```

The reduce function gives me this error:

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnknownError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[106], line 6
      3 valid_ds = create_dataset(validation_paths, validation_genres)
      5 # try using reduce: doesn't work
----> 6 print("Training dataset cardinality:", train_ds.reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy())
      8 # run a simple map before running the reduce
      9 print("Training dataset cardinality:", train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (x, y)).reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy())

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\dataset_ops.py:2767, in DatasetV2.reduce(self, initial_state, reduce_func, name)
   2763 if name:
   2764   metadata.name = _validate_and_encode(name)
   2765 return structure.from_compatible_tensor_list(
   2766     state_structure,
-> 2767     gen_dataset_ops.reduce_dataset(
   2768         dataset._variant_tensor,
   2769         structure.to_tensor_list(state_structure, initial_state),
   2770         reduce_func.captured_inputs,
   2771         f=reduce_func,
   2772         output_shapes=structure.get_flat_tensor_shapes(state_structure),
   2773         output_types=structure.get_flat_tensor_types(state_structure),
   2774         metadata=metadata.SerializeToString()))

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\gen_dataset_ops.py:6343, in reduce_dataset(input_dataset, initial_state, other_arguments, f, output_types, output_shapes, use_inter_op_parallelism, metadata, name)
   6341   return _result
   6342 except _core._NotOkStatusException as e:
-> 6343   _ops.raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6344 except _core._FallbackException:
   6345   pass

File ~\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py:6653, in raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name)
   6651 def raise_from_not_ok_status(e, name):
   6652   e.message += (" name: " + str(name if name is not None else ""))
-> 6653   raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None

UnknownError: {{function_node __wrapped__ReduceDataset_Targuments_0_Tstate_1_output_types_1_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__EagerPyFunc_Tin_1_Tout_1_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} TypeError: exclude_short_tracks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 266, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 144, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 151, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: exclude_short_tracks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'

 [Op:EagerPyFunc] name: 
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 266, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 144, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 151, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\data\ops\structured_function.py", line 210, in py_function_wrapper
    ret = self._func(*nested_args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_60496\783181910.py", line 26, in <lambda>
    ds = ds.filter(lambda x, y: tf.py_function(exclude_short_tracks, [x], tf.bool))

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\util\traceback_utils.py", line 153, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\framework\ops.py", line 6653, in raise_from_not_ok_status
    raise core._status_to_exception(e) from None  # pylint: disable=protected-access

tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.InvalidArgumentError: {{function_node __wrapped__EagerPyFunc_Tin_1_Tout_1_device_/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/device:CPU:0}} TypeError: exclude_short_tracks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 266, in __call__
    return func(device, token, args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 144, in __call__
    outputs = self._call(device, args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\ops\script_ops.py", line 151, in _call
    ret = self._func(*args)

  File "C:\Users\ashka\anaconda3\envs\tf\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\autograph\impl\api.py", line 643, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)

TypeError: exclude_short_tracks() missing 1 required positional argument: 'label'

 [Op:EagerPyFunc] name: 


     [[{{node EagerPyFunc}}]] [Op:ReduceDataset] name:
```

It seems like somehow the reduce function is calling "exclude_short_tracks", and because of that it's giving me an `InvalidArgumentError`. I honestly don't understand why this is the case. My "reduce_func" is just a simple `lambda x, _: x + 1`.

I have already tried passing a dataset through a simple map to see if it makes a difference:
`train_ds.map(lambda x, y: (x, y)).reduce(0, lambda x, _: x + 1).numpy()`, but I get the same behavior.

I have also tried `len(list(train_ds.as_numpy_iterator()))`; same result.

Two questions:

Why am I seeing this behavior? Where is the call to `exclude_short_tracks` made in the process?

Is there a suggested way to get the dataset's cardinality?

Comment: The error is in `exclude_short_tracks` and likely has nothing to do with the `reduce` call. The function is called because your dataset is filtered using that function, so to provide any data to reduce, it has to go through the filter first. Your `py_function` call seems faulty; you only provide a single input `x`, yet `exclude_short_tracks` takes two arguments.

Comment: @xdurch0 Nice catch! The problem was indeed with my `exclude_short_tracks` call. I thought calling `create_dataset` would throw any existing errors when I ran it in eager mode, so I assumed everything was fine before that point.

Comment: @xdurch0 I'd say just go ahead and post this as an answer, while also explaining why `create_dataset()` doesn't catch the errors.

Comment: The issue is that TF datasets are very "lazy" and many problems will not be caught when creating them, only once we actually iterate over them. I guess `reduce` requires iteration, and that's why the error occurs there.